# message reference in sms-deliver-pdu

Tags: android, sms

Upon sending an sms from a mobile phone, an sms-submit-pdu is returned by the smsc which has a
message reference/callback id (range: 0 to 255 , not so unique in a long queue of messages, but still..) and when the smsc delivers this message to the recipient, a sms-deliver pdu is generated and sent to the original sender of the message, most wikis and web sites have quoted that this delivery-pdu contains the message reference/callback id of the submit-pdu, but I just can't seem to find it, does it have such a thing?
If it has one, then the problem of differentiating delivery reports of smses sent in a loop might be solved.